# How to deal with issue with Dynamics365 RSAT certificate error?

Tags: dynamics-365

I have Dynamics365 OneBoxDev VHD 10.0.24 upgraded to 10.0.29.

Installed and configured RSAT by this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/perf-test/rsat/rsat-install-configure

[But encountered that error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ywz48.png)

[wif.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbCCh.png)

[tool settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlTW7.png)

What am i doing wrong?
Please help!

Find solution helps with my issue.

Answer (score 0):

below answer provided by Microsoft, it works for me

Please go to wif.config file and check the spn value:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txFfE.png)

Please update the spn value in wif.colnfig file in the VHD instance to 00000015-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 (this is the value of Finance and Operations app) and test the connection.